# Multi-index power series

Tags: summation, closed-form

What is closed-form expression for the summation

$$ S(n,m)=\sum_{|\alpha|=m} p^{\alpha} = \sum_{\alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n = m} \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{\alpha_i} $$
as a function of $n$ and $m$? Here $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)$ is a $n$-tuple of non-negative integers.

For specific values of $n$ the sum has a closed form, e.g. $S(1,m)=p_1^m, S(2,m)=\frac{p_2^{m+1}-p_1^{m+1}}{p_2-p_1}$, etc. I wonder if there is a more manageable form with few summations, even though there might be no closed form for the general expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that
$$S(3,m)=\frac{p_1^{m+2}}{(p_1-p_2)(p_1-p_3)}+\frac{p_2^{m+2}}{(p_2-p_1)(p_2-p_3)}+\frac{p_3^{m+2}}{(p_3-p_1)(p_3-p_2)}$$
which is promising.
$$S(k,m)=\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{p_i^{m+k-1}}{\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^k(p_i-p_j)}$$
To get that, use the recursion $$S(3,m)=S(2,m)+p_3S(2,m-1)+p_3^2S(2,m-2)+,,,$$
together with your formula for $S(2,m)$.

Comment: Good! The $S(k,m)$ formula seems to be correct. I could prove it by induction, assuming the identity $$\sum_{i=1}^k(\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^k(p_i-p_j)(p_{k+1}-p_i))^{-1}=(\prod_{j=1}^k(p_{k+1}-p_j))^{-1},$$ which is not obvious for me at all...

Comment: I think it involves the Lagrange interpolating polynomial for the constant function!

Comment: The identity contains the coefficient for $p_{k+1}^{m+k-1}$ in $S(k+1,m)$. On the other hand, it's easy to see that the coefficient for $p_{i}^{m+k-1}$ is $(\prod_{j=1, j\neq i}^{k+1}(p_j-p_i))^{-1}$. Since $S(k+1,m)$ is symmetric wrt $p_i$-s, it's also the coefficient for $i=k+1$, which proves the identity and the formula!