# Is there a way to find expansion of powers of multinomials without any coefficients?

Tags: exponentiation, multinomial-coefficients

For example, $(a + b + c)^3 = a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + 3ab^2 + 3ac^2 + 3a^2b + 3a^2c + 3bc^2 + 3b^2c + 6abc$
Knowing the value of a, b and c, is there a way to find this without the coefficients i.e. $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + ab^2 + ac^2 + a^2b + a^2c + bc^2 + b^2c + abc$ using previous values or some other way?

Comment: What do you want to find about the 2nd expression? Can you state it more clearly?

Comment: The sum without the coefficients in the original expression.

Comment: The number of different combinations  of a, b, and c is the number of sorted combinations. I need to find an easy way of computing this value without having to try every possible combination and adding it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1171385/multi-index-power-series) gives the formula you are looking for ($m=3$).

$$\frac{a^{m+2}}{(a-b)(a-c)}+\frac{b^{m+2}}{(b-a)(b-c)}+\frac{c^{m+2}}{(c-a)(c-b)}$$

Comment: That helped a lot! Thanks xivaxy.

Comment: Can this apply for four variables too? As in like $(a + b + c + d)^n$

Comment: Yes, check the question I mentioned.