# Multi Index Power Series

Tags: summation, closed-form, multinomial-theorem

What is the closed-form expression for the summation

$$ S(n,m)=\sum_{|\alpha|=m} p^{\alpha} = \sum_{\alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_n = m} \prod_{i=1}^n p_i^{\alpha_i} $$
as a function of $n$, $m$ and $p$? Here $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)$ is a $n$-tuple of non-negative integers.

This equation can also be seen as multinomial expansion without coefficients.

The answer to the question asked by xivaxy: [Multi-index power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1171385) doesn't work when $p_i$ = $p_j$ and $i$ != $j$.

Comment: Have you tried any examples etc?

Comment: An example includes p as {5, 5, 11}. We can't use the generalization in the previous answer.